# issue with creating method in js

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
var mango =  new Object ();
mango.color = "yellow";
mango.shape= "round";
mango.sweetness = 8;
Object.prototype.howSweetAmI = function () {
console.log("Hmm Hmm Good");
}
console.log(mango); 
</script>
```

Question:

I can change this line:  `Object.prototype.howSweetAmI` to `mango.howSweetAmI`, and both of them can work. But what is the difference between them? usually we use which way to create method?

Comment: try to put this : `console.log(this.color);` instead of : `console.log("Hmm Hmm Good");` and see the difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually you would not add anything to `Object.prototype`, because then it would be added to *everything*. It would be usable for example with `"".howSweetAmI()`, and that wouldn't make much sense.

Normally you have a specific type where you add methods to the prototype, for example:

```
function Fruit(color, shape, sweetness) {
  this.color = color;
  this.shape = shape;
  this.sweetness = sweetness;
}

Fruit.prototype.howSweetAmI = function() {
  return this.sweetness;
};

var mango = new Fruit("yellow", "round", 8);
```

Adding the method to the prototype means that all instances uses the same method. If you add a method as a property to the instance, only that instance has the method, and different instances can have different implementations of the method. For example:

```
var mango = new Fruit("yellow", "round", 8);
var banana = new Fruit("yellow", "bent", 70);

mango.howSweetAmI = function() { return this.sweetness; };
banana.howSweetAmI = function() { return this.sweetness * 0.1; };
```

Comment: +1 your snippet helped me to understand the flow of prototype :) thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a function to the `Object` prototype will make that function available on every javascript object. (`console.log(window.howSweetAmI)`). Moving it to `mango` will make it a property of that single object.